# curl scraping problem getting mail ids with javascript

Tags: curl, screen-scraping

I want to scrape mail ids from a page and have got a script which is running in most sites. But in some sites they are loading mail ids with javascript so curl cant able to load the contents of the page with mail ids. i mean here

`http://www.everynation.org/churches/church-directory/africa/zambia`

Here they are loading mailids with javascript. how to scrape it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps the webmaster is publishing these email addresses using Javascript to *prevent* them being scraped and you should respect those wishes.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than struggling with curl I recommend you use a higher level tool that can handle JavaScript. Here are articles I wrote about handling JavaScript with [chickenfoot](http://webscraping.com/blog/Scraping-JavaScript-based-web-pages-with-Chickenfoot/) and [webkit](http://webscraping.com/blog/Scraping-JavaScript-webpages-with-webkit/).

Answer (score 0):

I think Plumo pointed you in the right direction. I would add [Watir](http://watir.com/)